# How can I find the value of x given multiple Parallel Lines and multiple Transversals?

Tags: geometry, modular-arithmetic, transversality

Ive been given the following problem:
[image]

I was unable to figure out how to solve the problem, and I was told the answer was the following;
However, the program has failed to explain to me exactly how it got the answer... Looking online, I can only find solutions for single transversal, 2 line problems, which aren't necessarily difficult..
[image]

My question is, how exactly, piece by piece, do I find X given multiple transversals or parallel lines?

Comment: You might have been confused by the trick in the problem's figure: the segment with length 15 is drawn longer than the segment with length 25, which in my opinion is meant to mislead the students!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more parallel lines or transversals you just apply the "Parallel lines cut transversals into proportional segments." theorem for more than once. (This theorem is essentially Thales' Theorem.)

I created an example in the figure below. Since you had successfully obtained $x=5$ from the lower trapezoid, we can write the following for the upper trapezoid.
$$\frac{y}{3}=\frac{10}{x}=\frac{10}{5}\implies y=6$$
[image]

Comment: But how exactly are you getting 10/5? I guess thats the part I dont understand

Comment: Did you understand why $x=5$ in your original example; are you asking for its explanation? I thought you were only asking for a more complicated case.

Comment: Yeah, I dont understand how the answer was obtained in the first place. I dont know how the fractions were used to get x = 5

Comment: Draw a parallel line and form a triangle on the left like the one in Stinking Bishop's diagram. In a triangle, from Thales' Theorem the segments cut by the parallel lines are proportional (it basically comes from the similarity of the triangles).

Comment: Google "Side Splitter Theorem" and I think you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just reduce the problem to the problem with two lines by passing a line parallel to one of your lines - for example (sorry for sloppy drawing):

[image]